# VB.NET paint method?

Tags: vb.net

Is this the best way to paint images on a form? I have most of my experience in Java and little in VB.net. In Java there is repaint() that can be called? There is a Me.refresh(). Is this what you wnat to call when you have something to add to the form or to paint to the form.

Class:

```
    Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
        ' Create image. 
        Dim newImage As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\Pic\article-tip.gif")

        ' Create Point for upper-left corner of image. 
        Dim ulCorner As New Point(50, 50)

        ' Draw image to screen.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, ulCorner)

        Dim newImage2 As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\Pic\article-tip.gif")

        ' Create Point for upper-left corner of image. 
        Dim ulCorner2 As New Point(150, 150)

        ' Draw image to screen.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage2, ulCorner2)

    End Sub

End Class
```

I tried this code here with one button on the form with a click event

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim i As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint

        i = 0

        ' Create image. 
        Dim newImage As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\Pic\article-tip.gif")

        ' Create Point for upper-left corner of image. 
        Dim ulCorner As New Point(50, 50)

        ' Draw image to screen.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, ulCorner)

        Dim newImage2 As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\Pic\article-tip.gif")

        ' Create Point for upper-left corner of image. 
        Dim ulCorner2 As New Point(150, 150)

        ' Draw image to screen.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage2, ulCorner2)

        If i = 5 Then
            ' Create image. 
            Dim newImage3 As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\Pic\article-tip.gif")

            ' Create Point for upper-left corner of image. 
            Dim ulCorner3 As New Point(250, 250)

            ' Draw image to screen.
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage3, ulCorner3)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        i = 5
        Me.Refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Just Tried this code here:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        i = 5
        Me.Invalidate()
 End Sub
```

New Class just Tested:

```
Public Class Form2
    Dim newImage As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\Pic\article-tip.gif")
    Dim newImage2 As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\Pic\article-tip.gif")
    Dim newImage3 As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\Pic\article-tip.gif")

    Private bgImage As Bitmap
    Private srcImages As Image()

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)

        Dim img As Bitmap = Me.bgImage

        If (img Is Nothing) Then
            Me.bgImage = New Bitmap(Me.ClientSize.Width, Me.ClientSize.Height)
            img = Me.bgImage
        End If

        If (Not Me.srcImages Is Nothing) Then
        End If

        MyBase.OnPaint(e)

    End Sub

    Private Sub _Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.srcImages = New Image(3 - 1) {}
        Me.srcImages(0) = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\Pic\article-tip.gif")
        Me.srcImages(1) = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\Pic\article-tip.gif")
        Me.srcImages(2) = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\Pic\article-tip.gif")
    End Sub

    Private Sub _Disposed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Disposed
        If (Not Me.srcImages Is Nothing) Then
            For Each img As Image In Me.srcImages
                If (Not img Is Nothing) Then
                    img.Dispose()
                End If
            Next
            Me.srcImages = Nothing
        End If
        If (Not Me.bgImage Is Nothing) Then
            Me.bgImage.Dispose()
            Me.bgImage = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub _Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.SizeChanged, MyBase.Resize
        If (Not Me.bgImage Is Nothing) Then
            Me.bgImage.Dispose()
            Me.bgImage = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Invalidate()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why you want to paint your form? What is your requirement? you can use backgroundimage and backcolor properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `Me.Invalidate()` invalidates the entire surface of the control and causes the control to be redrawn.

I also suggest that you *don't* load your images in *every* paint cycle.
You could load the source images in the forms load event and destroy them when the form disposes.

```
Public Class Form1

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)

        Dim img As Bitmap = Me.bgImage

        If (img Is Nothing) Then
            Me.bgImage = New Bitmap(Me.ClientSize.Width, Me.ClientSize.Height)
            img = Me.bgImage
        End If

        'TODO: Draw and paint.
        If (Not Me.srcImages Is Nothing) Then

        End If

        MyBase.OnPaint(e)

    End Sub

    Private Sub _Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.srcImages = New Image(3 - 1) {}
        Me.srcImages(0) = Image.FromFile("...")
        Me.srcImages(1) = Image.FromFile("...")
        Me.srcImages(2) = Image.FromFile("...")
    End Sub

    Private Sub _Disposed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Disposed
        If (Not Me.srcImages Is Nothing) Then
            For Each img As Image In Me.srcImages
                If (Not img Is Nothing) Then
                    img.Dispose()
                End If
            Next
            Me.srcImages = Nothing
        End If
        If (Not Me.bgImage Is Nothing) Then
            Me.bgImage.Dispose()
            Me.bgImage = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub _Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.SizeChanged, MyBase.Resize
        If (Not Me.bgImage Is Nothing) Then
            Me.bgImage.Dispose()
            Me.bgImage = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private bgImage As Bitmap
    Private srcImages As Image()

End Class
```

Comment: Invalidate() -- The invalidate() isn't working like I think it is supposed to. I added some code above just like the one you posted above. I have included my own images and placed one button on the form that should repaint the form when I click that button. Nothing happens the images are not loaded. If you can can you take a look.

Comment: @DougHauf Refering to your edit: You don't do any painting in the `OnPaint` method.

Answer (score 4):

The 1st snippet shows no evidence of needing any help.  Nothing in the Paint event handler depends on the state of class so there's no reason to force a repaint.  Default painting is already good enough.

The 2nd snippet does, through the artificial `i` variable.  You'd always call `Me.Invalidate()` in such a case, that marks the entire client region of the form as requiring a repaint.  The UI then eventually gets a Paint event when nothing more important needs to be done.  Using `Me.Refresh()` works too but is heavy-handed and it is exceedingly rare to need it.  I can't think of a good example.

Note how [Invalidate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has some overloads, you can mark just a portion of the window to require repainting.  This is an optimization that makes painting more efficient.

As written, your program is likely to crash after using it for a while.  You must call the Dispose() method of the images you load.  Take a look at the VB.NET *Using* statement.  You'll want to pre-load the images so it doesn't happen while painting and won't happen repeatedly.  Following a Winforms programming tutorial or book is highly recommended to avoid these kind of traps.